# restart sever socket after x second

Tags: node.js, sockets, nodejs-server

I have a problem with my script below.
In fact I would like to restart the connection on the remote after x seconds.
I added the following code but the problem is that it does not restart every time...

I use this command to restart the socket:

`remotesocket.emit('close', new Error('forcefully error'));`

Complete code:

```
    require('dotenv').config()
    const date = require('date-and-time');
    const chalk = require('chalk');
    let util = require("util");
    const net = require('net')
    const now = new Date();

    const remotehost = process.env.REMOTE_HOST
    const remoteport = process.env.REMOTE_PORT
    const localhost = process.env.LOCAL_HOST || '0.0.0.0'
    const localport = process.env.LOCAL_PORT || 1010

    let sec = 0;
    let restart = false;

    let restart_count = 0;

    process.on("uncaughtException", function(error) {
    //console.error(error);
    });

    const server = net.createServer((localsocket) =\>
    {
    const remotesocket = new net.Socket();
    remotesocket.connect(remoteport, remotehost);

        localsocket.on('connect', () =>
        {
            console.log(`>>> connection #${server.connections} from  ${localsocket.remoteAddress}:${localsocket.remotePort}`);
        })
        
        localsocket.on('data', (data) =>
        {
           console.log(`${localsocket.remoteAddress}:${localsocket.remotePort} - writing data to remote`);
           console.log(`localsocket-data: ${data}`);
        
            if (restart){
               console.log(chalk.blueBright("Close connexion"));
               remotesocket.emit('close', new Error('forcefully error'));
               sec = 0;
               restart = false;
            }
        
        
            const flushed = remotesocket.write(data);
        
            if (!flushed)
            {
                console.log(' remote not flused; pausing local');
                localsocket.pause();
            }
        })
        
        remotesocket.on('data', (data) =>
        {
            console.log(`${localsocket.remoteAddress}:${localsocket.remotePort} - writing data to local`);
            console.log(`remotesocket-data: ${data}`);
        
            if (restart){
               console.log(chalk.blueBright("Close connexion"));
               remotesocket.emit('close', new Error('forcefully error'));
               sec = 0;
               restart = false;
            }
        
            const flushed = localsocket.write(data);
        
            if (!flushed)
            {
                console.log(' local not flushed; pausing remote');
                remotesocket.pause();
            }
        })
        
        localsocket.on('drain', () =>
        {
            console.log(`${localsocket.remoteAddress}:${localsocket.remotePort} - resuming remote`);
            remotesocket.resume();
        })
        
        localsocket.on('close', () =>
        {
            console.log(`${localsocket.remoteAddress}:${localsocket.remotePort} - closing local`);
            remotesocket.end();
        })
        
        remotesocket.on('close', () =>
        {
            console.log(`${localsocket.remoteAddress}:${localsocket.remotePort} - closing local`);
            localsocket.end();
        });

    });

    setInterval(()=\> {
    sec++;

        if (sec >= 3400){
            restart_count++;
        }
        
        console.log(restart_count);
        console.log('second:' + sec);

    },1000);

    server.listen(localport);

    console.log(`redirecting connections from 0.0.0.0:${localport} to ${remotehost}:${remoteport}`);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You aren't restarting any server socket here. You are restarting the client side of a connection.

Comment: yes that's right, disconnecting clients not from the server....